# Possible to automatically install eGPU drivers on Ubuntu 20.04? Boot gets stuck after fresh install when eGPU connected

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, 20.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop connected to an eGPU. I had previously connected this eGPU to the same laptop, but running Ubuntu 18.04. It was working fine, except I had to manually select the integrated/eGPU depending on which one I wanted to use.

For the new install, I haved tried two configurations.

1. I installed Ubuntu 20.04, with the eGPU **disconnected**. This worked perfectly fine until I tried installing the NVIDIA drivers (460). After installing CUDA Toolkit (11.0) and the NVIDIA drivers, I rebooted, registered the drivers in secure boot, and got stuck on a black screen with the text:

> /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, m/n files, p/q blocks

2. I installed Ubuntu 20.04, with the eGPU **connected**. I selected the option that 3rd party drivers be installed and Ubuntu then automatically installed the NVIDIA drivers (450). However, after the reboot and registering the drivers in secure boot, I again get stuck on a black screen with the text:

> /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, m/n files, p/q blocks

Is it possible to install Ubuntu to automatically use an eGPU? Has anyone had issues with newer NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 20.04 and eGPU?

Also, I am trying to understand better how to modify the xorg.conf file to support two GPUs. I would like the NVIDIA GPU to be used if connected, else use the Intel integrated GPU. Is this possible?

P.S. I am writing here not on an eGPU/NVIDIA forum as this is an issue related to the Ubuntu install.

Comment: What is eGPU???

Comment: An external GPU. Specifically, I am using the HP Accelerator

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to automatically install the GPU drivers and have the OS work on install.

This is because the login screen uses wayland not X11, which doesn't seem to support external GPUs. It is possible to [modify the login screen settings to use X11](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-machine-learning-on-a-linux-laptop-with-an-external-gpu/), which then makes it possible to use the eGPU. However, this is a manual step and not automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I think the key is to add `Option "AllowExternalGpus" "true"` to the nvidia conf in `/usr/share/X11/xorg`, e.g. `10-nvidia.conf`.

I added the following as `20-nvidia.conf`:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowExternalGpus" "true"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

It's a copy of my `10-nvidia.conf` with the option to allow external GPUs added.